# How to set dropdown values to null using ng-change angular js?

Tags: angularjs

- I have one dropdown lets say **`Drop-down A`**, based on option selected from that, new dropdowns will be populated. For example,on selection of `option 1` from `Drop-down A`, 2 new dropdowns will be showed. similarly on selection of other options new dropdowns will be populated and other dropdowns will be removed.
- Now when I select options from newly populated  dropdowns,I can get their value.
- Problem comes when I select ***option 1*** from ***Drop-down A*** and then select values from newly generated dropdowns, but now I wish to change ***Drop-down A*** slection to ***option 2***. Now based on current selection, new dropdowns will be generated.
  So if now I post the values, my controller still shows, previous option 1 values.

  So how can I change unselected dropdown values to `null`?
  [*See Plunker*](https://plnkr.co/edit/cNMVBG5ADIdY3MIPAXQj?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you problem right, I would prefer to create a function in controller  to reset object.

```
$scope.onChange = function(){
   $scope.obj = {};
}
```

And call it on `ng-change`

```
<select ng-model="selectC" ng-change="onChange()"  name="subSub" id="main">
```

[Wokring plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fBfYiGVQPKmBenq3fK20?p=preview)